# Permission for uploading media doesnot support

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi in woocommerce there is a role `shop_manager`.usually he can upload files.But by theme is not supporting file upload by `shop_manager`.

There error comes : `Sorry, you are not allowed to upload files.`

Then i added attachment capability manually :

```
function add_shop_manager_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );

    $role->add_cap( 'edit_attachments' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_attachments' );
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_attachments' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_shop_manager_caps');
```

And it shows :

```
$role = get_role('shop_manager');
   foreach( $role->capabilities as $name => $val ){
   echo $name . "<br />";
}
```

But still same error : 
**Sorry, you are not allowed to upload files.**

Comment: First, check web server error log files, likely permission errors. Then ensure the upload destination directory is writable by Apache, which usually runs as a system user named "www-data"  or "nobody" How to do that depends on what your web host provides. SSH, FTP, web based file manager etc..

Comment: @DuaneLortie but it works for Admin